# a property of global elements in the category of sets

Tags: category-theory

In the category $\operatorname{Set}$, choose a singleton $*$.  Since $*$ is a terminal object, a morphism $e: * \to X$ is also known as a [global element](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/global+element) of $X$.  Here the global elements determine the morphisms from $X$, in the sense that they have the following property: two morphisms $f$, $f': X \to Y$ are equal if and only if $fe = f'e$ for all $e: * \to X$.

Does this property have a name?  Can we describe the categories that have it?

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for this, but I would call it "globally separated".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object $X$ with the property that $\text{Hom}(X, -)$ is faithful is called a *generator* or a *[separator](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator)*. Categories such that the terminal object is a generator are somewhat rare (and I don't know a term for this condition); examples include $\text{Top}$ and the category of varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$. Nonexamples include any nontrivial abelian category (since here the terminal object is the zero object) and the category of rings (since here the terminal object is the zero ring).

Even very small perturbations of $\text{Set}$ don't have this property. For example, in the category $G\text{-Set}$ of $G$-sets ($G$ some group), the functor $\text{Hom}(1, -)$ is the functor of $G$-invariants, and this is almost never faithful. Similarly, in the category $\text{Sh}(X)$ of sheaves of sets on a topological space $X$, the functor $\text{Hom}(1, -)$ is the functor of global sections, and this is again almost never faithful.

**Edit:** In topos theory a slightly stronger condition is called being [well-pointed](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-pointed+topos).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that although $*$ is a generator of the category of varieties over an algebraically closed field, this already fails if the field is not algebraically closed and/or we consider general schemes instead of just varieties.